# Pushing an empty array into the state(userAnswer array) for every question asked so I can use those arrays to keep track of user answers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

Here is what I have so far

```
AssignUserAnswerArray = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < SurveyData.length; i++) {
            console.log("I am in the for loop assigning arrays")
            this.setState(prevstate => {
                let test = [...prevstate.userAnswers];
                test.push([]);
                return ({ userAnswers: test })

            })

        }   
    }

state = {
        userAnswers: [],
       currentQuestion: 0,
        //options: []
    }
let test = AssignUserAnswerArray();
console.log(test)
```

output:
26 I am in the for loop assigning arrays

0

The console.log repeats the correct number of times I am just not pushing an empty array to the state correctly. When AssignUserAnswerArray gets called it should make userAnswers contain as many empty arrays as for loop iterations.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? It seems to do just what it's supposed to without error.

Comment: The userAnswer array in state does not seem to get any empty arrays added to it. I call const test = this.state.userAnswers.length; console.log(test); and I get 0 logged

Comment: Well, for one, if you are using `const`, you will be unable to change test.

Comment: Please add the output of your code to your question.

Comment: The return ({userAsnwers: test }) should be return ({ userAnswers: test })

Comment: Fixed typo, get the same result though. I have tried this using a few different syntax  and now I assume I am doing something wrong other than syntax but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand why you have it like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < SurveyData.length; i++) {
            console.log("I am in the for loop assigning arrays")
            this.setState(prevstate => {
                let test = [...prevstate.userAnswers];
                test.push([]);
                return ({ userAnswers: test })

            })

        }
```

perhaps something like:

```js
this.setState(prevstate => {
    let test = [...prevstate.userAnswers];
    for (var i = 0; i < SurveyData.length; i++) {
       test.push([]);
    }
    return {
        userAnswers: test
    }; 
});
```

?

Comment: I like this approach much better. I'm not sure if this fixed my problem but I decided to console.log(test) every time it pushes and it is pushing the correct number of black arrays onto test, but when I call this.AssignUserAnswerArray(); and console.log(this.state.userAnswers.length) in my componentDidMount I still get 0 for some reason. Am I not updating the state correctly? or is .length not working like I think it should?

Comment: So do you also call `this.AssignUserAnswerArray()` in your `componentDidMount` ?
Keep in mind that: `this.setState` is asynchronous so logging `this.state.userAnswers.length`, immediately after calling `this.AssignUserAnswerArray()` shouldn't give you the correct output.

Comment: If you need to see the state update: perhaps, you could use the react debugger or maybe log it in the `render` method (it would rerender once the state has actually updated). alternately. `this.setState()` has a callback as second param:
`this.setState(()=>{}, callback)` which would give you the updated state values

Comment: I call `this.AssignUserAnswerArray()` in a function that loads the rest of the state. And that function gets called in `componentDidMount`. When I call `AssignUserAsnwerArray` I should have all the blank arrays I need to `manupilate` so I shouldn't need to call it more than ounce and the very beginning which is why I attached to componentDidMount. I will try the callback

Comment: Yea @RileyBeckham , it's a situation of waiting for the state to be updated first.

Comment: When I call `console.log(this.state.userAnswers.length)` in the `render()`I get 26! yay! Was my problem that I console.log the userAwsners length in the wrong spot the whole time? If I had it right from the very beginning that would be frustrating. Never the less thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Your assumption is correct. You probably had it right from the beginning. You were logging at the wrong time (spot) (before the state has actually had any time to be updated)